# Is par eminence a French term?

Tags: meaning, french

Is **par eminence** a French term? What does it mean?
Here is a sample sentence from The New York Times"

For more than two centuries there has always been somebody who, like the Duke of Cambridge, has been popularly known among his contemporaries as "the Duke" **par eminence**, if not invariably par excellence. Immediately after the Restoration, George Monk, Duke of Albemarle, was "the Duke" in common parlance all over the country, and from his death until the death of Charles II, "the Duke" was James, Duke of York, who became King as James II.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Etymologically it’s from French: *par éminence*. However, I would consider it an English expression considering it has enough usage in English to be included in dictionaries like the Oxford English Dictionary (even though it is marked as “now rare”), where it is defined as:

> More distinguished or eminent than others of the same kind; supreme.